# @Query select without join

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Good evening!

I have database structure  [][1] and I'm trying to make @Query which affects on several databases. I want to do that without JOIN.
I made that request:

```
@Query("SELECT md FROM MeteringDevice md where md.carCatalog.kindOfCar.kindName = :kindName")
List<MeteringDevice> findAllByReportTypeName(@Param("kindName") String kindName);
```

Fields carCatalog, kindOfCar and kindName belong to different Entity Classes;

Can I use in that case in @Query plain Select or I need to use JOIN?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use JPA method, it will work same as join: No need to use @Query annotation.

List < MateringDevice> findAllByCarCatalog_KindName(String kindName);

carCalalog is object of another class(Relationship or Association) that has field name kindName.

Comment: In complex queries JPA method name is very long and difficult to read that spoils code style so I need to use @Query annotation

Comment: it's a simple jpa methods and we also need to take care of performance issues, so use jpa methods first then try another solutions